# Is there any way to reduce a cat's shedding?

Tags: cats, shedding

My long-haired cat sheds a lot, so I was wondering if there was any way to reduce how much he sheds. I brush him almost daily, and that seems to help keep the shed hair from getting everywhere, but is there any way to slow the shedding process in the first place?

Note: They have Canidae dry food available to eat during the day, and I give them a can of Canidae wet food for supper.

Comment: Which food does your cat eat? Low-quality, fillers-filled (yep) foods like Whiskas (poisonous) or Cat Chow generate a lot of shedding.

Comment: I know folks who regularly give their long hair cats a lion cut every summer (keeps them cooler, reduces maintanance at a busy time of year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your longhaired cat is healthy - and is having no dietary issues, I’d say that you are doing just fine. Few people with longhaired cats are happy aout the quantities of hair that they shed, but it’s just part of the package that comes with being a cat’s parent.

Because of the time spent grooming your cat, it’s likely that you are more likely to discover unusual physical symptoms, like lumps, weight los, and possibly dehydration before other less conscientious cat owners. Good for you!