# What can I do about my cat shedding too much fur on my clothing?

Tags: cats, grooming, shedding

I have a long haired white cat that sheds (much more than my black short-haired cat). Every time you hug him, you end up covered with fur. It seems natural for him though; he doesn't get bald and all and has been seen by the vet.  The main issue for me is the amount of fur I get on my favorite black shirt or pants every time I carry him.

I find it difficult to even carry him because I wear dark clothing most of the time. Every time I put him on my lap, his fur is all over my clothes.

What could be causing this and/or how do I minimize the shedding?

Comment: Better, now expand to say how often you brush him, and if the shedding occurs more at a certain time of year what time of year is that, in relation to the seasons where you live.  January is a different season in Canada than in Australia. and the tropics don't have significant seasons.

Comment: Long haired cat?  If so that just comes with the breed of cat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a dog or a cat to shed?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/what-causes-a-dog-or-a-cat-to-shed) See also [Is there any way to reduce a cat's shedding?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5486/481)

Comment: If all the previous cats were short-hair cats, a long hair cat is going to appear to shed more. White fur also shows up more clearly, so it might just seem like it's more compared to the dark fur that is hard to see.

Comment: I guess I should just change my favorite color in clothing then? I always wear black shirt and I'm a hugger, so... yeah.

Comment: I think it's time for you to develop a preference for white clothes.  Embrace the reality. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the amount of shedding is normal, I don't think there's anything you can do to lessen it. However, you can somewhat reduce the amount that ends up on *you*, by grooming him frequently. Most cats love being groomed, so it will be a bonding experience for both of you. Start slowly, a little bit at a time, so he can get used to it.

To remove the maximum amount of loose hair, try a slicker brush. That's a flat, metal brush with small, fine wire bristles. The bristles are bent backward to help remove loose hair.

Another option is one of those small rubber brushes that fit in your palm.

Comment: And for what remains (because you're always going to get *some* hair on your clothes), keep a lint roller handy.

Comment: Or wear clothing that matches your cat's fur. Though most cats have just enough color variation to visibly shed on anything... Or learn to spin and knit cat-fur sweaters. Or just decide it isn't worth worrying about, which is my usual solution for anything short of a formal suit. "Yes, I have a cat; why do you ask... oh, yeah, right."

Answer (score 2):

In hot weather months, you can reduce shedding and help the cat handle the heat by cutting the hair short - to the skin (lion cut) or about the length of a short haired cat (teddy bear cut).

Regular brushing helps. A way to keep hair off your clothes is to keep a towel handy and put the cat on the towel on your lap.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the amount of fur a cat malts over your furniture and clothes you could try a deshedder brush. I have four cats and use one of these; two love it and the other two hate it. As this is my first post I'm not sure if I can share the brand here but you can search online shops for this tool. They're not usually cheap for a decent one.

Comment: Product **type** recommendations are generally permitted in my experience with the SE community, as long as you confirm you have no affiliation with the brand used as an example. It may also help to describe why the features of the type of brush you use is superior to those of other designs.

Comment: The de-shedder brush is called the Furminator - there are other products available that are similar to this one. I chose this version because it had very good reviews and looked good quality. 
Thanks Doresroom!

Comment: Different cats like different kinds of comb or brush; different cats have finer or thicker fur, or more or less undercoat.... so no grooming tool is ideal for all of them. Plan to experiment a bit.